# AWS-CLI Upload only one file in lambda (update-function-code)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am using AWS-CLI to my files into my lambda (because i want to ship with my own boto3).

The problem is that I have to upload the whole project (my files + boto3) in my lambda.

I have to wait ~5min each time (my connection is kinda bad)

The question is: can i upload only the files that i want (as git)?

Currently I use this command:

```
zip -r function.zip . && aws lambda update-function-code --function-name MYFUNC --zip-file fileb://function.zip && rm function.zip
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lambda layer for your common files and attach it to your lambda.

Where you can make direct upload for frequently changing files.

[Lambda layers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/#:%7E:text=A%20Lambda%20layer%20is%20an,directory%20in%20the%20execution%20environment.)